# Следует ли в содержимом слайса объекты указывать через указатель на GO?

Tags: golang, slice

Коллеги,

возник вопрос....
у меня есть набор объектов, которые я сохраняю в слайсе, например:

```
type MyObject struct {

}

var sl []MyObject

....

myObject := MyObject{}
sl = append(sl, myObject)
```

и на сколько правильно было бы сохранить в слайсе указатель на этот объект, а не его значение?

```
var sl []*MyObject

....

myObject := &MyObject{}
sl = append(sl, myObject)
```

И еще вопрос, если я делаю копирование слайса и в первом и во втором случае, то на сколько будет отличаться операция копирования по ресурсам?

```
slNew := sl // вариант 1:  var sl []*MyObject
slNew := sl // вариант 2:  var sl []MyObject
```

как еще дополнительный вопрос, если мы делаем итерацию по слайсу:

```
    for _, value := range slNew  // sl []*MyObject

или  
    for _, value := range slNew  // sl []MyObject
```

то в первом варианте у нас в value  копируется только указатель на объект, а во втором варианте сам объект.....

**вот собственно и вопрос, следует ли в содержимом слайса объекты указывать через указатель на GO?**

Спасибо за помощь разобраться в данном вопросе!

Comment: Вроде уже разбирали эту тему. Вот тут например: https://medium.com/@philpearl/bad-go-slices-of-pointers-ed3c06b8bb41 А вообще много можно прочитать погуглив: "Slices of structs vs. slices of pointers"

Comment: уже есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430725/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-go/1430943#1430943)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Неявные ссылки (указатели) в Go](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430725/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-go)

Comment: Коллеги, вопрос не в повторение, вопрос в проф. точке зрения, только - это.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ИМХО, размысшления об указателях и структурах - это тяжёлое наследие С++ с его конструктором копирования и семантикой сдвига. Go устроен принципиально иначе. Это язык со сборщиком мусора, значительно более простой семантикой и, как следствие, продвинутым оптимизатором. Вот правда, оптимизатор в Go творит какую-то запредельную жесть. Вы как-нибудь поглядите в ассемблер бинарника, собранного с оптимизацией и отключенными данными отладки: вообще ничего похожего на исходный код!

К чему это я. К тому, что в Go весьма продвинутый статический анализатор использования объекта (так называемый escape analysis). Если объект используется только для чтения, то его копия создаваться не будет. Это к вопросу о `for _, value := range slNew`. Если внутри цикла `value` не будет модифицироваться, то сто-пудово компилятор не будет создавать временный объект для хранения `value`.

Теперь про "копирование" слайса. Инструкция `slNew := sl` не копирует слайс. Эта инструкция создаёт небольшой объект типа [`SliceHeader`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#SliceHeader), копирует в эту структуру указатель на собственно память с данными слайса, длину слайса и максимальный размер слайса, и всё. Если вам нужно создать именно дубликат слайса, то есть слайс с теми же данными, но расположенный в другой области памяти, вам нужно использовать встроенную функцию [`copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy):

```
    slNew := make([]MyStruct, len(sl))
    copy(slNew, sl)
```

Эта пара операций, разумеется, гораздо быстрее в случае слайса указателей, просто в силу того, что указатель занимает всего 8 байт, а структуры могут быть гораздо большего размера. Копирование массивов из тысячи элементов: [бенчмарк здесь](https://go.dev/play/p/97DoyH9ug03)

```
BenchmarkSlicePointers-8          432214          2962 ns/op        8192 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkSliceNoPointers-8        135276         10121 ns/op       32768 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

Бенчмарк показывает, что копирование указателей в три с половиной раза быстрее, чем копирование массива структур, но это напрямую вытекает из того, что в бенчмарке массив структур в четыре раза больше по размеру.

Кстати, благодаря тому, что при простом присваивании копируется только заголовок слайса, а не сам слайс, то при передаче в функции слайс передаётся фактически по ссылке: https://go.dev/play/p/0XpYmxDpr_w

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var slice []int
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        slice = append(slice, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(slice)
    modify(slice, 10)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

func modify(slice []int, value int) {
    slice[0] = value
}
```

Результат:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
[10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

**ИТОГО**

Я всегда пользуюсь слайсами структур и стараюсь не связываться с указателями. Оптимизатор Go умнее меня, и лучше ему не мешать, ИМХО.

Comment: Отличное объяснение, СПАСИБО ВАМ!